# How do I create an unified Archive folder in Outlook for Mac 2016?

Tags: ms-office

I've just installed Microsoft Office 2016 and I can't figure out how to create an unified Archive folder just like it does by default for Inbox, Sent items, etc.

[[image: Screenshot][1]]

I'd like my Archive folder to display all elements from the Archive folders in both the iCloud and Exchange accounts, and if possible be displayed at the top just like the default folders are.

(also if someone has a tip on how to change the display order so that the junk mail folder is right below the deleted items that would be awesome)

Regards.